# Problem with class loading in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am so confused with the behaviour of the following code.

```
def file = new File("C:/MyeclipseWorkspace/SampleGroovyProject/src/templates/apixmls/one.groovy")
println file.getText()
println getClass()
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
println parent
```

When I run this as a groovy script, I get the required output as following

```
class ConsoleScript10
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@18b995c
```

---

Rather when I just make a simple change of encasing the script within a function and executing it, It behaves in a weird manner as follows:

For the change made,

```
static void foo(){
def file = new File("C:/MyeclipseWorkspace/SampleGroovyProject/src/templates/apixmls/one.groovy")
println file.getText()
println getClass()
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
println parent
}
foo()
```

The above code gives me a different output as follows:

```
class java.lang.Class
null
```

---

Can you please tell me what's wrong with the second code snippet. I would want to implement the class loading within a function and get the required output as in code snippet 1. Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you take a look at the final outcome using Groovy's AST browser in groovyConsole you'll see the following:

```
    public class script1302766776488 extends groovy.lang.Script { 
        // ...
        public static void foo() {
            this.println(this.getClass())
            java.lang.ClassLoader parent = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            this.println(parent)
        }
        // ...
```

as the static foo method is part of the generated script class descendant, a call to this.getClass() simply returns java.lang.Class because you are in a static method and the class of the script1302766776488 class is java.lang.Class.

if you need a reference to the current class loader just call getClassLoader() (without getClass()).